# Error "undefined is not a function" everytime a 'supabase.auth.function' is called on a React Native app

Tags: react-native, supabase

I am trying to create a login page for my Expo React Native app but no matter what, it does not seem to detect anything I call in supabase.auth.x

Here is the code for my App.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import HomeBasicStack from "./routes/HomeBasicStack.js";
import LoginStack from "./routes/LoginStack.js";
import supabase from "./supabase-service.js";

export default function App() {
  // prettier-ignore
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAuth(supabase.auth.session());

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setAuth(session);
    });
  });

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {auth ? <HomeBasicStack /> : <LoginStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I have followed instructions from many sources 1:1 on how to set up the authenticator, including that of the Expo Supabase documentation but none of them seem to work at all, spewing up error codes that no one from my extensive search has had other than me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (supabase && supabase.auth) {
        setAuth(supabase.auth.session());
        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
        setAuth(session);
      });
    }
  });
```